# de Laval nozzle

Tags: fluid-dynamics

My question is for de Laval nozzle

Given the inlet pressure $p_i$, ambient pressure $p_e$, and the geometry of the Laval nozzle ( local Area/Throat area : A/A*) relationship, what is the mach number at any point using the parameters:

inlet reservoir pressure $p_0$
ambient pressure $p_b$
throat area/Local area $A_t/A_l$
relationship at any point over the length of the nozzle .

Answer (score 0):

The "standard" equation which is used to calculate the flow inside a de Laval nozzle is
$$
\frac{1}{c} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}c}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{1}{M^2-1} \cdot \frac1A \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}A}{\mathrm{d}x}
\quad\mbox{,}
$$
which is a relationship between the cross-section area $A$ of your nozzle and the gas velocity $c$ with the [Mach number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_number) $M$ as parameter ($x$ is the location). This equation is derived from the [Euler equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)) using the [continuity equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation). The derivation is given for example on the [German Wikipedia article on the de Laval nozzle](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavald%C3%BCse). (I assume derivations in other languages can also be found in the internet.)

To my knowledge there is no solution in closed form (= an equation) for the flow inside a stream filament (*) where you can just plug in the geometry and then calculate all flow properties.

There is some [course materials from Stanford](https://web.stanford.edu/~cantwell/AA210A_Course_Material/AA210A_Course_Notes/AA210_Fundamentals_of_Compressible_Flow_Ch_10_BJ_Cantwell.pdf) which on first look seem to give lots of valuable explanations on this topic if you are further interested.

(*) Note: I don't know if "stream filament" is the correct term. What I mean is a fluid tube confined by streamlines. The German term is *Stromfaden*.